# How can I iterate over rows in a dataframe, and for each row, cut every 3 values and stack the values vertically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge data frame that have 100 rows and 126900 columns. Each row in this dataframe represents a road trip of a vehicle. The columns are repetitive like this: longitude, latitude, timestamp, longitude, latitude, timestamp, longitude, latitude, timestamp, etc. Each row shows the a sequence of instant locations of the vehicle in each second. Now for each row (each trip), I want to kind of split the repetitive columns and stack the values vertically. So the transformed dataframe should be a 3-columns dataframe.

[I am sorry I am new to Stackoverflow and do not know how to insert table like this. Please see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JYj8.png)

I am thinking to use a double for loop with iterrow() method like this:

for index, row in df.iterrows():
for i in range(len(df)):

But I am stuck here and do not know what to do next. And it seems that looping through rows/columns in a huge dataframe might be generally a bad practice. Can anyone help me on this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for c in range (0, len(df.columns)-1, 3):
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df[df.columns[c:3]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this, but the original dataframe has many columns, how can I loop through the columns and make the code more dynamic?